# How to get the numeric value of missing values in a PySpark column?

Tags: pyspark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I am working with the **OpenFoodFacts dataset using PySpark**. There's quite a lot of columns which are entirely made up of **missing values** and I want to drop said columns. I have been looking up ways to retrieve the number of missing values on each column, but they are displayed in a table format instead of actually giving me the numeric value of the total null values.

The following code shows the **number of missing values in a column** but displays it in a **table format**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when, count
data.select([count(when(isnan("column") | col("column").isNull(), "column")]).show()
```

I have tried the following codes:

- This one does not work as intended as it doesn't drop any columns (as expected)

```
for c in data.columns:
    if(data.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)]) == data.count()):
        data = data.drop(c)

data.show()
```

- This one I am currently trying but takes ages to execute

```
for c in data.columns:
    if(data.filter(data[c].isNull()).count() == data.count()):
        data = data.drop(c)

data.show()
```

Is there a way to get **ONLY the number?** Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the number instead of showing in the table format, you need to use the `.collect()`, which is:

```
list_of_values = data.select([count(when(isnan("column") | col("column").isNull(), "column")]).collect()
```

What you get is a list of Row, which contain all the information in the table.